static_assert vs C_ASSERT - which one to use?
I have a general C++ / Windows question for coding standards regarding compile-time assertions.
static_assert is C++11 and language/compiler supported;
C_ASSERT is a define from winnt.h
So, if I have C++ Windows code - which one should I use? Why? What are the advantages of one over the other?
I tested both - there is a difference in the error message.

In general, portable code is preferable to implementation-specific code.

Especially if using non-portable code doesn’t gain you anything.

Keep in mind that the Win32 API has to support both C and C++, new and old, so it uses a lot of abstractions that allow it to do different things under different configurations to maintain a consistent interface. If you are targeting C++ only, especially C++11 or later, then there is simply no reason to use C_ASSERT over static_assert.  static_assert is standard C++. C_ASSERT is a Microsoft-specific invention.

Regarding portability, you also have to ask if the code needs to be portable to older toolchains. I.e. if it is more likely to need to be built on an older visual studio that doesn't support it in the language than needing to be built on a non-Windows platform.

@RemyLebeau And even in C since C11, it also has static_assert (when <assert.h> is included).

Unless you target platform/compiler/... which doesn't have static_assert, I don't see the point of not using the standard way.

Based on the documentation, you should use static_assert over C_ASSERT.

If you are limited to C++11, it requires you to provide a message explaining why the compilation failed.
If you don't want to display a message, moving to C++17 gives you a similar definition to C_ASSERT.
It is preferred in C++ to avoid macro's whenever possible.
It is more likely to be compatible with all the different compile time features that C++ has compared to the macro.
It is platform-independent and performs the same task


Very comprehensive answer! Thank you!
